# Get string after first word

Tags: javascript, split

I'm currently trying to split up sentence and get the string after the first word.

What I've currently tried:

```
var datetime = "28 Dec2.55pm";
datetime.split(/[0-9]+/);
console.log(datetime);
// This returns back all the words and no numbers.
```

Expected result:

```
// Ethier
28 Dec 2.55pm
// Or
[0] => 28 Dec
[1] => 2.55pm
```

I would like some guidence for this, you don't have to give a full answer just some guidance.

Comment: `split` removes the string passed as separator, if you split by any number, all the numbers will be stripped off. [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) might be better choise for the task ..?

Comment: How are you obtaining the initial string that you want to split, are you creating it (programatically or otherwise)? If you are, I'd suggest changing the code that creates the string rather than trying to compensate for, or correct, it after the fact.

Comment: @DavidThomas The data is received as the string. I'm not the once creating the data.

Comment: Is the format consistent? Or are you looking to break on some logic? As Teemu said, right now your logic is to consider numbers the splitting characters. I'm a bit curious what you thought split did.

Comment: split with regex?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `split` modifies the string, but *it does not do so*. I am not providing a solution, but I will show how to actually use `split`: `var x = datetime.split(/[0-9]+/); console.log(x);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var datetime = '28 Dec2.55pm';

// Split datetime on spaces
var split = datetime.split(' ');

var parsed = [
  split[0], // First element is the day
  split[1].substr(0, 3), // First three characters of second element represent name of the month
  split[1].substr(3, split[1].length - 3) // All characters in second element from index 3 onward present the time
];

console.log(parsed);
```

This code assumes that the month name is always 3 characters in length.

---

Those looking for a much cleaner solution I'd suggest **@Toto**'s answer.

Comment: Providing any kind of explanation would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `split`, I'd use `match`:

```js
var datetime = "28 Dec2.55pm";
var d = datetime.match(/^(\d+\s[a-z]+)(.+)$/i);
console.log(d);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/           : regex delimiter
  ^         : begining of string
  (         : start group 1
    \d+     : 1 or more digits
    \s      : a space
    [a-z]+  : 1 or more letter
  )         : end group 1
  (         : start group 2
    .+      : 1 or more any characters
  )         : end group 2
  $         : end of string
/i          : regex delimiter, case insensitive
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a regex this might be of use. Its not a perfect tailored fit but its close enough, having some assumptions:

```
var myRe = /(\d{1,2}\s\w{3})(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\w{2})/g;
var myArray = myRe.exec('28 Dec2.55pm');

console.log(myArray);
```

It assumes:

- 1-2 digits date separated with space with 3 characters for month as 1st capture
- 1-2 digits of hours separated with . form 1-2 digits of minutes and pm am after

It will give you what you need quick but it lacks failing to mach in case your time is wrong, data is wrong, pm am could be GG or anything etc..

Answer (score -1):

Maybe stupid answer but I assume that you always have the same structure, right? It means "day space three-letter-month not-space exact time".

It the months are 3 letters and days are written as 01 and there is always space you can simply divide it at 7th character

If the above is true with exception that days are written as "1" and not "01", than easiest approach is to look to second character - if it is number, divide at 7th place, if it is space divide at 6th place.